# Reading CSV with pandas and ignoring commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv with one column and a bunch of quotes.  I want to read it into a pandas Series so that each row in the csv is an entry. However, it seems like when I use `pd.read_csv`, the reader cuts off the line when it finds a comma.

How do I ignore commas and read the entire cell in excel into an object in a series?

The data is as follows: one column and a lot of rows. One entry in a row is like: "Hector went to the bathroom. He was nervous, as he'd never been there before" so my program cuts off the sentence at 'nervous' because of the comma that follows.

Comment: Use the `sep` parameter to define a separator that is not the default `,`

Comment: use the sep keyword. Set sep = '|' or something

Comment: So, `sep` separates the items in a cell into the columns, but then for a new row it will use the new row in excel, correct?

Comment: what does your data look like? If you're reading a csv file, splitting on commas is exactly what it's supposed to do. After all, the "CS" in "CSV" stands for comma-separated.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually have a CSV file. You just have a plain text file with a bunch of lines. Don't try to process it as a csv file.

Comment: Interesting.. should I read the .csv sheet as a text file then, or do I have to convert it to a .txt before proceeding?

Comment: There's nothing to convert. It sounds like it already is a plain text file. Or, do what someone else suggested and pick a separator that you know isn't part of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a text file with one entry per line. As such you could load your file in by setting `delimiter='\n'`, and give your single column a name:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('input.txt', delimiter='\n', names=['text'])
print(data['text'][0])
```

Would give:

```
Hector went to the bathroom. He was nervous, as he'd never been there before
```